# PasswordAuthentication=no flag does not work on one strange host

Tags: ssh, password, prompt, interactive

On my source REDHAT Linux 7 host i fire this command to never prompt for password and passwordless login

```
ssh -i /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@<target-host> -vvv
```

This works for a list of host and I can determine if ssh is working or not non-interactively [with no password prompt].

However, on one particular host `10.0.66.66` it prompts me for the password despite `-o PasswordAuthentication` flag.

```
ssh -i /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@10.0.66.66 -vvv
```

Debug of the output of the above `ssh` command is as below:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.0.66.66" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.66.66 [10.0.66.66] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_2.2
debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_2.2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.66.66:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:315
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.66.66
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: languages stoc: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 2034/4095
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:HCTDUmgLFN9OFvbuusL5Z9hZbUXQyZTqS0hGwkbapxA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:315
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.66.66
debug1: Host '10.0.66.66' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:315
debug2: bits set: 1961/4095
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa (0x55e36c8cde60), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:2019)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:2019)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Can you please let me know how to enforce no-password prompt for hosts like 10.0.66.66 when `PasswordAuthentication=no` option not helping?

Comment: Check the logs (i.e. `/var/log/auth.log`) on the server in question for errors - maybe wrong permssions on `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be enforcing this on the server side and not the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

You're being prompted for "keyboard-interactive" authentication, which is technically separate from "password" authentication. Keyboard-interactive is like password, but the server provides the prompt message. It's often used with things like [RSA tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_SecurID) and [yubikeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YubiKey).

You can disable keyboard-interactive by setting [KbdInteractiveAuthentication](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#KbdInteractiveAuthentication) to "no":

> **KbdInteractiveAuthentication**
> Specifies whether to use keyboard-interactive authentication. The argument to this keyword must be yes (the default) or no

Alternately, if you're not running this command interactively, you may want to enable [batch mode](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#BatchMode):

> **BatchMode**
> If set to yes, user interaction such as password prompts and host key confirmation requests will be disabled. This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no user is present to interact with ssh(1). The argument must be yes or no (the default).

Comment: used by things like RSA tokens and Yubikeys, and by everything else that uses PAM, AFAIK. Though I always thought `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` controls that (at least on the server), and now I'm not at all sure how that relates to `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`

Comment: @Kenster it still prompts for this recommendation `ssh -i /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no root@10.0.66.66` however, `ssh -i /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa -o BatchMode=yes root@10.0.66.66` worked !!

Comment: When i try all these three recommendations its works !! Here is what works for me ` ssh -i /app/axmw/ssh_keys/id_rsa -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no root@10.0.66.66`


Any changes to the above will fail and I will be prompted for password. @Kenster can you please update your answer to include ` -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no`